# Microsoft Graph API: Fetch attachments for a particular email not an entire email thread

Tags: email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, email-attachments, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using Microsoft Graph API to get attachments of particular email.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/messages/<message_id>/attachments
```

Above API returns attachments from previous conversation thread as well.

Suppose a mail was started and it had bunch of replies with attachments and my latest email contains only **one attachment **and in entire email there are like** 5 attachments** with latest message-id if i try to fetch attachment instead of returning 1 attachment, it returns all attachment.

Is there any filter available just to get that particular attachment of the given mail.

i tried to get attachments of that particular sent mail but instead i am getting attachments of entire thread

Comment: What kind of attachments are they? I mean whether they are inline attachments directly within the message body or standard attachments? Check the property isInline on each attachment

Comment: Both inline as well as standard attachments, if you add any of them you get all attachments of entire mail thread

Comment: Your issue is really weird, and shouldn't work like that, for threads there is another endpoint. Are you sure you're retrieving message-id correctly? 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user-id>/messages/<message-id>/attachments` returns me only that's message specific attachment, not the whole thread's. The only case when there are attachments included from previous message, when it's forwarded, but in that case they are really attached to the new message